# How to find $g'(x)$ when $g(x)=\int_{5x+1}^{x^2} \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, fundamental-solution

How do I find $g'(x)$ when $$g(x)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{5x+1}^{x^2}\,\dfrac {\sin\,t}{t}\;dt$$
My attempt$$f(t)=\dfrac{\sin t}{t}$$
applying FTC$$g'(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x^2)^{x^2}}{x^2}-\dfrac{\sin 5x+1}{5x+1}$$
But I got the incorrect answer.

Comment: the answer should be $$-5\,{\frac {\sin \left( 5\,x+1 \right) }{5\,x+1}}+2\,{\frac {\sin
 \left( {x}^{2} \right) }{x}}
$$

Comment: There is a theorem in your notes saying what the derivative of $$g(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt$$ is, use it!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pretty failsafe method:

Let $F$ be a primitive of your integrand $t\mapsto\sin(t)/t$. Then
$$
g(x)=\int_{5x+1}^{x^2}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt=F(x^2)-F(5x+1).
$$
Thus, by the chain rule,
$$
\begin{aligned}
g'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}F(x^2)-\frac{d}{dx}F(5x+1)\\
&=F'(x^2)\cdot2x-F'(5x+1)\cdot 5\\
&=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}\cdot 2x-\frac{\sin(5x+1)}{5x+1}\cdot 5.
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the chain rule with [Fundamental Theorem of calculus](http://www.actucation.com/calculus-2/basics-of-definite-integration/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus)

$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}g'(x)&=f(h(x))\,h'(x)-f(\phi(x))\,\phi'(x)\\&=f(x^2)×\dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}{x^2}-f(5x+1)×\dfrac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(5x+1)\\&=\dfrac {\sin\,x^2}{x^2}×(2x)-\dfrac {\sin(5x+1)}{(5x+1)}×5\\&=\dfrac {2x\,\sin\,x^2}{x^2}-\dfrac {-5\,\sin(5x+1)}{(5x+1)}\end{split}\end{equation}$$

Comment: If $h(x)=x^2$ in one place it cannot be $1/x^2$ in the next...

Comment: @mickep. I've mistakenly typed. Btw Thanks